# Device for Bootloader installation Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, secure-boot, ahci

I am planning to dual boot Ubuntu Budgie and Windows 10 on my Dell Inspiron 7591. It has a 512gb ssd with Windows 10 installed. I plan to buy another 512gb ssd and install ubuntu there. I just want to know in the device for bootloader installation should I choose the first or create an efi partition in second ssd and more importantly what is the difference between them.In which of the following method I would still be able to use windows recovery environment. I understand the selected one will need to be placed higher in the boot order. Also is it always necessary to change sata mode from raid to ahci regardless of them being nvme ssd. I am installing in uefi mode with secure boot on.

Answer (score 0):

Your GRUB bootloader needs to be found by the BIOS/UEFI startup sequence on the primary startup device.  With the intended setup you describe, this will be the device Windows boots from -- likely a dedicated boot partition, if your computer was originally a Win10 machine.

The easiest way to be sure this is right is to verify with the partition manager during Ubuntu installation -- if you run this after installing the new SSD hardware, there'll be one device with two or three partitions on it, and one with none; GRUB needs to go on the first bootable partition on the drive that wasn't empty.

Comment: I understand your answer completely. If I instead create an efi partition and install grub on it an then set the second ssd as first in boot order will that be any better?

Comment: Should not make any difference. You can have one ESP - efi system partition per device and I always do that with a new drive or flash drive with full install. I have found a way to force Ubiquity to install to an ESP on sdb and it works. I primarily use sdb's ESP as backup for sda's ESP. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 You can manually install grub or use Boot-Repair to install grub to sdb as grub will, it just is Ubiquity installer will only use first ESP it finds.

Comment: Thank you. I'l go with the first way.So how do install grub to sdb as a backup option? Is is necessary to create an esp on 2nd drive or just /root will do? So I suppose Ubiquity refers to ubuntu installer? I didn't understand that mount unmount thing.